# Is there an element for "download now" in Github?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'd like to have a neat "Download Now" box with a link to the latest release on my Github project start page - so that people who came there because they wanted to download and install the release don't have to guess that there're "releases" and the latest one and so on.

Is there a readily available element for that either in Github markdown or perhaps elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of yet, but wanted to say that this is a great idea! I am working with git right now and would love a feature like that.